# How can we use custom structs/enums with the Model and Predicate macros?

Tags: swift, swift-data

Swift 5.9 and the new SwiftData framework introduce the `@Model` and `#Predicate` macros. We can now use custom enums and structs in our our models, like so:

```
@Model
final class Item {
    var name: Name
    var nature: Nature

    struct Name: Codable {
        let base: String
        let suffix: String?
    }

    enum Nature: Int, Codable {
        case foo = 0
        case bar = 1
        case baz = 2
    }

    init(name: Name, nature: Nature) {
        self.name = name
        self.nature = nature
    }
}
```

But how can we use them in a `Predicate`? All of these examples fail:

```
// Member access without an explicit base is not allowed in this predicate (from macro 'Predicate')
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { $0.nature == .foo }

// Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type.
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { $0.nature.rawValue == Item.Nature.foo.rawValue }

// No compile error, but causes the Xcode Preview to crash when used inside a @Query.
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { $0.name.base.contains("Hello, world!") }

// Optional chaining is not supported here in this predicate. Use the flatMap(_:) function explicitly instead. (from macro 'Predicate').
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { $0.name.suffix?.contains("Hello, world!") ?? false }
```

Comment: The first one the error is pretty self explanatory `{ $0.nature == Item.Nature.foo }`. The last one you can avoid the optional chaining like this `($0.name.suffix ?? "").contains("Hello, world!")`

Comment: `#Predicate<Item> { $0.nature == Item.Nature.foo }` produces the error `Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to freeze the comparison value outside of the predicate closure:

```swift
let foo = Item.Nature.foo
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { $0.nature == foo }
```

Not sure about the `name` issue, but it'd probably be easier if `Name` was a @Model itself and a @Relationship instead of a Codable.

Answer (score 0):

// Optional chaining is not supported here in this predicate. Use the flatMap(_:) function explicitly instead. (from macro 'Predicate').

```
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { $0.name.suffix?.contains("Hello, world!") ?? false }

-->

let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { $0.name.suffix.flatMap { $0.contains("Hello, world!") } == true }
```